# Use value gotten controller in Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have a controller that sends data to my Ajax function based on it's request, It searches for a value based on what was gotten from ajax, then it sends the search results to the ajax function based on the query in the controller. How can i use the data, below is an illustration of how i want to use the data in php form, when i alert the data it comes in this form `[object Object]`

**CONSOLE.LOG BRINGS THIS**

```
{…}

pasts: (3) […]

0: {…}

booking_id: "260618-00017"

booking_status: "BOOKED"

channel_id: 4
​​​
check_in: "2018-06-26"
​​​
check_out: "2018-06-27"
​​​
comments: null
​​​
created_at: "2018-06-26 15:34:28"
​​​
currency_code: null
​​​
guest: Object { id: 17, first_name: "msklsd", last_name: "klld;sld", … }
​​​
guest_id: 17
​​​
id: 15
​​​
is_staying: 0
​​​
made_by: "Room Hub"
​​​
number_of_guests: 7
​​​
paid_status: null
​​​
property_id: 11
​​​
reservation_payment_id: null
​​​
stay_id: null
​​​
updated_at: "2018-06-26 15:34:28"
​​​
__proto__: Object { … }
```

**SAMPLE PHP FORM**

```
@foreach($pasts as $past)
<tr class="bg-white div-hover room-reserve" id="reserved" data-id="{{$past->id}}" style="cursor: pointer;">
<td>{{$past->guest['first_name']}}  {{$past->guest['last_name']}}</td>
<td><img src="/{{$past->channel['icon']}}" alt="" style="margin:0;padding:0; width:50px;height:50px; border-radius:50%;"></td>
{{-- <td>{{$reservation->property['name']}}</td> --}}
<td>@if(isset($past->reservationDetails[0]->number_of_rooms))@if($past->reservationDetails[0]->number_of_rooms  >1)
    {{$past->reservationDetails[0]->number_of_rooms}}&nbsp;{{$past->reservationDetails[0]->room_category[0]->description}}s
    @else {{$past->reservationDetails[0]->room_category[0]->description}} @endif @endif

</td>
<td>{{$past->number_of_guests}}</td>
<td>{{$past->channel['name']}}</td>
<td>{{date('d/m/Y',(strtotime($past->check_in)))}} to {{date('d/m/Y',(strtotime($past->check_out)))}}</td>
<td>
          <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm p-0 px-1 reject-booking-request" data-reservation-id="">Reject</button>
          <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm p-0 px-1 accept-booking-request" data-reservation-id="">Accept</button>
      </td></tr>@endforeach
```

**THE AJAX FUNCTION**

```
 $('#search-btn').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
  let search = $('#search').val();
  if (search != '') {
      $.ajax({
          type: 'post',
          url: '{{action('ReservationController@searchPastReservations')}}',
          data: {searchValue: search},
      //    dataType: 'json',
          success: function (pasts) {
              alert(pasts);
            //  document.getElementById("expiry_label").innerHTML = "Trial End Date: " + result;
          }
      });
  }

  });
```

**THE CONTROLLER**

```
public function searchPastReservations(Request $request){
$ts = strtotime('today');
$today= date('Y-m-d', $ts);
$defaultPropertyId = (session()->get('default_property'))->id;
$property_id =  $defaultPropertyId ;
$searchValue = $request->searchValue;
//   if (isset)
if ($searchValue && !empty($searchValue)){
    $pasts = Reservation::with("Guest")->where('booking_status','BOOKED')
        ->where('property_id', $property_id)->where('check_out', '<', $today)
        ->whereHas('guest', function($q) use($searchValue) {
            // Query the name field in status table
            $q->where('first_name', 'like', "%" . $searchValue ."%")->orWhere('last_name', 'like', "%" . $searchValue ."%");
            // '=' is optional
        })->orderBy('check_in', 'asc')->get();
    return response()->json(array('pasts' => $pasts));
}}
```

Comment: use console.log instead of alert and see what is output

Comment: So what does `alert(pasts);` show you? I would recommend using `console.log(pasts);` instead since you then will see the actual object in the console.

Comment: Please recheck the question I just added the console.log's output

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to access the data as `pasts['pasts']` in your AJAX function, because the PHP call to `array('pasts' => $pasts)` is creating an associative array with the data stored under the key "pasts". I.e.,

```
 $('#search-btn').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
  let search = $('#search').val();
  if (search != '') {
      $.ajax({
          type: 'post',
          url: '{{action('ReservationController@searchPastReservations')}}',
          data: {searchValue: search},
      //    dataType: 'json',
          success: function (pasts) {
              console.log(pasts['pasts']);
            //  document.getElementById("expiry_label").innerHTML = "Trial End Date: " + result;
          }
      });
  }

  });
```